# Bootstrap: "max-width" on columns prevents "flex-grow-1" from working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a column be minimum 50% wide but fill the space that is left when there is space left. How do I accomplish that by using bootstrap? When I use "flex-grow-1" it does not work, because Bootstrap adds a "max-width: 50%" on my .col-6 column, in addition to the "flex-basis: 50%".

What I CAN do is add another rule on the column, saying "max-width: 100%" to override the bootstrap value. However, I am thinking there must be a "Bootstrap way" to do this. Is there?

Comment: the issue is not bootstrap but you are ussing the wrong class .. what you want is not a col-6 but simply col

Comment: That is not correct, I need the column to be minimum 50% width and depending on the screen size other minimum width / flex-basis.

Comment: this is not what col-6 is made for as you already notice. You can use col AND add your own CSS to it

Comment: I am aware of that, I was just wondering if there is a "bootstrap" way of handling this, just to get a clean solution. Thanks anyways